Wordpress Generated a list of page from button with AJAX
I am new in coding and I have issues to understand how Ajax works. I created a button which allows to generated a page in wordpress that can be edited after. I want that when I click on the button it will be added to a section under the button " generated page" where all the pages ( titles, dates) will be displayed. ( after fixing that I will add edit button and delete button) I want to retrieved these data of the post table without reload the page. Here is my code, it displays nothing under the title :

/**
 * Class WoosterPartnerPresentation
 * Sets up functionalities for displaying presentation content in the Wooster plugin.
 */
class WoosterPartnerPresentation
{
    /**
     * Constructor function for initializing the class.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        ob_start();
        // Hooks the presentation content function to the wooster_presentation_content action.
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterShowPresentation'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'checkElementplugingisactive'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSection'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSectionSetup'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'create_post')); //admin init is triggered when wp admin is initialized
        add_action('wp_ajax_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);


    }
    /**
     * Callback function to display presentation content.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterShowPresentation()
    {
        // FIXME: Concatenate the content in one variable and echo it at the end.
        echo '<div class="wooster-presentation">';
        echo '<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    /**
     * Add a section for display Elementor plugin state
     * @return void
     */
    public function checkElementplugingisactive()
    {
        add_settings_section('partner_badges_section1', __('Vérification Activation Elementor ', 'wooster-partner'), array($this, 'renderActivePlugin'), 'wooster_gutenberg', array());
    }
    public function ispluginElementorActive()
    {
        return is_plugin_active('elementor/elementor.php') ? true : false;
    }
    /***
     * Method rend to display all the page constructeur active or not
     */
    public function renderActivePlugin()
    {
        $elementorStatus = $this->ispluginElementorActive() ? "Elementor activé" : "Elementor désactivé";
        // $diviStatus = $this->ispluginDiviActive() ? "Divi activé" : "Divi désactivé";
        // Display the result
        echo $elementorStatus  . ".";
    }
    /*
     * Add a new section for the Form to select the page constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterPartnerPluginSectionSetup()
    {
        // Add a new section to a settings page.
        add_settings_section('partner_badges_section2', __('Choississez votre constructeur de page'), array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSection'), 'wooster_form', array());
    }

    /**
     * Callback function to display the form for selecting the page constructor.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterPartnerPluginSection()
    {
?>
        <?php
        do_settings_sections('wooster_gutenberg');
        ?>
        <h1>Choississez votre constructeur de page</h1><?php
        do_settings_sections('wooster_form');
        // Conditionally display the buttons based on the presence and activation of Elementor plugin
        if ($this->ispluginElementorActive()) {
            ?>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="gutenberg">
                    <button type="submit" style="margin-right: 10px;">Gutenberg</button>
                </form>
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-elementor" value="elementor">
                    <button type="submit">Elementor</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="gutenberg">
                    <button type="submit">Gutenberg</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="generated-pages">
        <h2>Liste des pages générées</h2>
        <!-- Pages will be appended here -->
    </div>

    <script>
    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Create a FormData object from the form
            const formData = new FormData(form);

            // Add the action name to the FormData object
            formData.append('action', 'create_post');

            // AJAX call
            fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Append new page to the list
                const pageElement = document.createElement('p');
                pageElement.textContent = `Title: ${data.title}, Date: ${data.date}`;
                document.getElementById('generated-pages').appendChild(pageElement);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php

    }
    /**
     * Create a new post with the content from the JSON file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function create_post()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            // Read the JSON file
            $json_data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/partner.json');

            // Check if the JSON file was read successfully
            if ($json_data === false) {
                echo "Erreur de lecture du fichier JSON.";
                return;
            }

            // Decode the JSON data
            $block_data = json_decode($json_data, true);

            // Check if the JSON data was decoded successfully
            if ($block_data === null) {
                echo "Erreur lors du décodage du fichier JSON.";
                return;
            }

            // Retrieve the title, content, and sync status from the JSON data
            $title = isset($block_data['title']) ? $block_data['title'] : '';
            $content = isset($block_data['content']) ? $block_data['content'] : '';
            $sync_status = isset($block_data['syncStatus']) ? $block_data['syncStatus'] : 'draft';
            $img_url = isset($block_data['img_url']) ? $block_data['img_url'] : array();

            // Create a new post page
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_status' => $sync_status,
                'post_type' => 'page', // You can change this as per your requirement
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

            if ($post_id) {
                // Get the title and date of the generated page
                $generated_title = get_the_title($post_id);
                $generated_date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);

                // Construct HTML markup for the generated page information
                $generated_html = '<p>Title: ' . $generated_title . ', Date: ' . $generated_date . '</p>';

                // Echo the generated HTML markup
                echo $generated_html;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Download an image from a URL and attach it to a post.
     *
     * @param string $image_url The URL of the image to download.
     * @param int $post_id The ID of the post to attach the image to.
     * @return int|WP_Error The attachment ID if successful, or a WP_Error object on failure.
     */

    public function download_image($image_url, $post_id)
    {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        // Check if the image has already been attached to the post
        // TODO: Study the behavior of the error_log() function. It might be interesting to have an error tracking file to be able to fix them.
        $attachment_id = $this->get_attachment_id_by_url($image_url);
        if ($attachment_id) {
            // error_log("Found existing attachment ID: $attachment_id");
        } else {
            // Download the image and get the attachment ID
            // TODO: Add the AVIF format to the list of supported image formats with the flter apply_filters( ‘image_sideload_extensions’, string[] $allowed_extensions, string $file )
            $attachment_id = media_sideload_image($image_url, $post_id, null, 'id');
            if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                // error_log("Error downloading image: " . $attachment_id->get_error_message());
            } else {
                // error_log("Downloaded image and got attachment ID: $attachment_id");
            }
        }

        return $attachment_id;
    }
    /**
     * Get the attachment ID of an image by its URL.
     *
     * @param string $url The URL of the image.
     * @return int|false The attachment ID if found, or false if not found.
     */
    public function get_attachment_id_by_url($url)
    {
        // Query to retrieve the attachment ID by the image URL
        // FIXME: Use another method to retrieve the attachment ID by the image URL if it possible.
        global $wpdb;
        $attachment = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid = %s", $url));
        return $attachment ? (int) $attachment : false;
    }
}

new WoosterPartnerPresentation();


Your create_post method responds with either plain text, or HTML. But in your client-side code, you try to parse the response as JSON, .then(response => response.json()) - of course that will fail.
